# addOnfailurelistener being called when I try uploading an image to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nebu5.jpg)I am new to firebase storage and I am trying to upload an image to firebase just so I could learn it. My app has a button. When I click on it. Image gets displayed on image view. The image gets displayed correctly, but that image is not stored to firebase storage. I have added the necessary code (OnClickListener of button[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfIZJ.jpg)) from firebase website to upload that image to storage. But the image isnt uploaded and addOnfailurelistener gets called (I am using a toast in this method).  Can anybody let me know why it is not being uploaded on firebase?

Comment: Please post an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code (or pictures of any text really). Post the actual code/text instead. Having the actual code/text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual code and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase needs [Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) version 9.4.0 or newer in order to work, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), so try to update it and check again.

Also, check if you have specified the appropriate rules for your Firebase Project. By default, Firebase Storage allows only authenticated users, but you can change it to public.

Go to the "Rules" tab of the "Storage" section in the console, and replace the code you see by that:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/your-bucket-id.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

where `your-bucket-id` put the address shown in the "Files" tab in the console (without gs://).